# How can I link two selects without having any conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two different collections of integers I need to put side by side. These values are not linked together in any way, they are just numbers that will be used for inserts later. I have tried this:

```
select A.COLUMN_VALUE as a, B.COLUMN_VALUE as b
from table(sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(123, 456)) A, table(sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(654, 321)) B;
```

Which gives this result – value A seems to be duplicated:

```
+---+---+
|A  |B  |
+---+---+
|123|654|
|123|321|
|456|654|
|456|321|
+---+---+
```

While I need it to be like this:

```
+---+---+
|A  |B  |
+---+---+
|123|654|
|456|321|
+---+---+
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all` or `join`.  Assuming you have the same length:

```
select A.COLUMN_VALUE as a, B.COLUMN_VALUE as b
from (select a.column_value, rownum as rn
      from table(sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(123, 456)) A
     ) a join
     (select b.column_value, rownum as rn
      form table(sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(654, 321))
     ) b
     on a.rn = b.rn;
```

This assigns a row number to each row and then joins on that.  `join` assumes the two lists have the same length.  If not, use `full join`:

```
select A.COLUMN_VALUE as a, B.COLUMN_VALUE as b
from (select a.column_value, rownum as rn
      from table(sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(123, 456)) A
     ) a full join
     (select b.column_value, rownum as rn
      form table(sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(654, 321))
     ) b
     on a.rn = b.rn;
```